# Angular dom sanitize not working correctly

Tags: html, angular, angular-dom-sanitizer

I used angular dom sanitizer to get html from a text area. It works perfectly for the first time after rendering the whole project, but the second time after revisit the component I got this message:

> SafeValue must use [property]=binding: My text (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss).

I already pass the content with property binding using the inner-html property

```
const desc=this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.ticket.description);
this.ticket.description = desc;
<p class="desc" [innerHTML]="ticket.description"></p>
```

I expected my plain text but i got that output described above.

Comment: In which method do you call the sanitizer? Please include the context in which the call is made.

Comment: oh yeah sorry, i called it in the ngOnInit method

Comment: You realize you're actually bypassing sanitization, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can bind directly like below:

```
<p class="desc" [innerHTML]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(ticket.description)"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

binding method in html leads to lot of ambiguity as follow. that method keeps on hitting by html, in your case in ngOninit it is working fine that means your logic is working fine ,  now write same logic in ngonchanges(keep it in ngonint
 too) it will work fine

```html
<p class="desc" [innerHTML]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(ticket.description)"></p>
```